# Why do we need $x \neq c$ in $(\epsilon, \delta)$ definition of limits?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

We have the following $(\epsilon, \delta)$ definition of limits:

> $$
> \lim_{x \rightarrow \  c} f(x) = L
> \;
> \text{iff} \\
> \forall \epsilon > 0 \;\;\;
> \exists \delta > 0 \;\;\;
> \forall x \in Dom(f)\;\;\;
> 0 < |x - c| < \delta \implies
> |f(x) - L| < \epsilon.
> $$

I understand everything in the definition except for this part:

> $$
> \color{red} 0 \color{red} <\; |x - c| < \delta
> $$

Why do we need explicitly state that $| x - c|$ is greater than zero? Obviously it means that $x$ can not be equal to $c$. But I don't understand what wrong is happening when $x = c$ so we need to explicitly avoid this case in the definition. I know that $f$ might not be defined at $c$ at all but we say in the definition that $x \in Dom(f)$ so in case if $c \not \in Dom(f)$ it will never be equal to $x$. What am I missing here?

Comment: If $x=c$, then $c$ is within the domain of $f$ and we don't need a limit.

Comment: If you don't exclude $x=c$ when $c$ is in the domain, then you have to introduce another definition to deal with removable discontinuities in functions like $f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x=0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

Comment: Limit is best thought as behavior $\textit{near}$ a point rather than $\textit{at}$ a point. That is why you do not include the point in the domain.

Comment: What you are describing is the case with the discrete topology by using open set definition of limits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}x^2, & x \ne 0\\ 1, & x=0 \end{cases}
$$

Do you want $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ to exist? If you want it to exist and be zero, you need to rule out $x=c$ in the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Because if $f$ is defined differently at $c$ than its 'limit' (i.e. removable discontinuity), you will get the wrong answer.

Comment: It's more like you'll be defining limits in a way that requires continuity, when it is useful to not do that. It's not really "the wrong answer".

Comment: @JoshuaWang There are no right or wrong answers here, just better or worse definitions, depending on the context.