# Why must we have $0<|x-p|$ in the definition of function limits?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

The definition of a function limit is given in my lecture notes as:

$$f(x)\rightarrow L \text{ as } x\rightarrow p \text{ if } \forall \varepsilon>0, \exists \delta>0 \text{ such that }\forall x,\color{red}{0<|x-p|}<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$$

Why do we demand $x\neq p$?

In my lecture notes I also note that the definition for continuity of a function at $p$ stipulates only that $|x-p|<\delta$ and not this additional inequality - why the difference?

Comment: Note that I can't link to these notes as I'm not allowed to distribute them - but the question should contain all that is needed as is.

Comment: Limits concern the behavior of a function, or a sequence, *near* a given value, not at it.  The idea being that the function might well be ill-defined at the value, while still sensible enough nearby to get useful information.  There are, of course, cases where the expression makes perfect sense at the indicated value and in those cases it can be interesting to compare the actual value to the value obtained by the limit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we need $x \neq c$ in $(\epsilon, \delta)$ definition of limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3868253/why-do-we-need-x-neq-c-in-epsilon-delta-definition-of-limits)

Comment: Ah whoops I had a good look but still managed to miss that this is a duplicate - you are right. However, I'm now reluctant to delete this as I must say @lulu 's comment answers my question much better than any answers on the post you linked to... What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

An example could be the function
\begin{align*}
f:[0,1]\to[0,1] \quad f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }x\in [0,1) \\
1 & \text{if }x = 1 
\end{cases} \: .
\end{align*}
The idea is that the function is constantly zero on the half-open interval $[0,1)$, and then suddenly jumps up to $1$ at $x=1$. The above definition allows one to determine that the limit of the function at $x=1$ is $L=0$, but if we did not ensure $x\neq p$, we could never find a $\delta$ small enough to give a unique limit, and thus a limit would not be defined.

This is a way of showing that the above function is not continuous - indeed, a function is continuous at $p$ if and only if the limit is defined and agrees with $f(p)$. This is then contained in the definition if you leave out the inequality $0<|x-p|$.

Comment: why do you use an example where only the limit from the left side can be calculated and not a more general example?

Comment: @miracle173 I find that the simpler an example is, the better it is at conveying the central idea. Here the point was that sometimes limits only exist when you leave out the case $x=p$, which I think is an important part of answering the question. I had no intention of making other points, and so a more general (and thus, necessarily more complicated) example would only cloud my intention.

Comment: "I find that the simpler an example is, the better it is at conveying the central idea" I think so, too. But I can't see why assuming that there only exists a limit from the left side is a simplification.  From my point of view this makes the example more complicated. But that is probably a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as Mr Tim said a function need NOT ne defined at p in order to have existence of the limit. For instance domf=(-1,0)U(0,1) and f(x)=0 on the domain. Then clearly
$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$=O despite the fact that the function is not defined at O. The value at p has NOTHING to do with the limit and its existence!